# In C# XAML Windows 8 Application Is It Possible Not to Use XAML

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have come across with something on one of my colleague's code who is recently coding for a Win 8 Metro Style App(**C# XAML**) as me. The point that made me curious is that he did not use any XAML code(other than the declaration statements in .xaml file) while he wrote the application and it seems the app works. So can anyone tell me that **why/where** should I use XAML or **why/where** should I not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Its a matter of preference. Some people prefer doing minimum XAML and creating everything in C# (code behind) and some prefer the oposite. I personally prefer doing as much work as possible in XAML. It is declarative and you can express fairly complex constructs in it while it is still very expressive and readable. I think you can understand a XAML construct easier than the equivalent C# construct.

Comment: Have you ever experienced any performance issue between those approaches?

Comment: @FıratTuncer in theory the XAML approach should be slower, because the XAML file must be parsed firt at start but I never had any performance problems